# Spring boot api consumes not working with multipart for file and json

Tags: spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I have a rest API made with spring-boot and this API is taking a file and JSON body, it seems like the JSON body makes the API only accepts JSON as it's appearing on the client `insomnia` or `postman`

so it's producing a `415` HTTP error

this is the API

```
@ApiOperation("Add New Type")
@PostMapping(value = "/add", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ResponseWrapper<Boolean>> addType(
        @RequestPart(name = "body") TypeRegistrationRequest typeRegistrationRequest,
        @RequestPart(name = "file", required = true) MultipartFile logoFile,
        HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
    String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    return ResponseEntity.ok(null);

}
```

this when I call the api

[image]

I put the content type in insomnia as `multipart/form-data`

Comment: have you tried `@RequestParam` instead of `@RequestPart`

Comment: this is working but somehow jakson is not serializing the Json from string to the Java pojo  ! the problem is the same code was working on an older project, so I made a new project and tried a clean API without any additional configs on spring boot and same result!